# htaccess redirect issue in godaddy

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a htaccess which will redirect all subdomain to parent domain except one domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.theonlytutorials\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(blog|www)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theonlytutorials.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This code was working fine in my previous hosting. But in Godaddy it doesn't seems to be working.

It is redirecting, but to the exact hosting location.

One of my URL structure:

```
www.theonlytutorials.com/video/58/4496/ChessBaseGmbH
```

Instead it is redirecting to:

```
www.theonlytutorials.com/others/tutorials/video/58/4496/ChessBaseGmbH
```

Where **others / tutorials** are the folders created in my hosting

Comment: You either have other rules that do that, or your script does, or you've been cached from others redirect.

Answer (score 0):

On Go Daddy (and probably some other Hosts) the site folder names should be included in your redirect code.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site-folder-name/video/58/4496/ChessBaseGmbH/$ http://the full URL here where you want the redirect point to
```

If you wanted to redirect a link from the /blog/ folder / site to another site

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/video/58/4496/ChessBaseGmbH/$ http://the full URL here where you want the redirect point to
```

Let's say you want to do a redirect from a site that is in this folder /others/ and you want to redirect to your root domain.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/others/video/58/4496/ChessBaseGmbH/$ http://the full URL here to your root domain where you want the redirect to point to
```

And logically the same thing would probably be true if you have this folder structure /others/another-nested-folder/

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/others/another-nested-folder/video/58/4496/ChessBaseGmbH/$ http://the full URL here to your root domain where you want the redirect to point to
```